# Calculation of sum of referenced values

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I have below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Order>
    <Bundle>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>3</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>3</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
    </Bundle>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>12.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>13.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>14.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <value>15.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <value>16.00</value>
    </item>
</Order>
```

Trying to transform in to a html table of below format

```
 --------------------------------
    ItemList - <Totalvalue of items (value in seperate nodes) in ItemList >
    ItemList - <Totalvalue of items (value in seperate nodes) in ItemList >
    ItemList - <Totalvalue of items (value in seperate nodes) in ItemList >
```

Example Result -

```
ItemResult - 44.00  (sum of value of item with id 1 + 4 + 5)
ItemResult - 43.00
etc
```

---

Here's the XSL I started

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

    <table border="1">

      <xsl:for-each select="Order/Bundle/itemList">
      <tr>
        <td>TotalValue</td>
        <td><xsl:call-template name="priceSum">
    <xsl:with-param name="item" />
  </xsl:call-template> </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="priceSum">
  <xsl:param name="item"/>    
     <xsl:value-of select='sum(itemList/item/id/value)'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I could not get the sum of values of those item ids belonging to the itemlist group..

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Updated, Sorry for confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="OrderItemById" match="Order/item" use="id"/>

 <xsl:template match="itemList">
     ItemList - <xsl:value-of select=
      "sum(key('OrderItemById', item/id)/value)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Order>
    <Bundle>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>3</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
        <itemList>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>3</id>
            </item>
        </itemList>
    </Bundle>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>12.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>13.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>14.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <value>15.00</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <value>16.00</value>
    </item>
</Order>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
 ItemList - 43
 ItemList - 42
 ItemList - 41
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need to get sum of values of those items.  itemList has multiple items associated, each item in the bottom of XML has a value associated to it. so I would like get the value of those items which are in each itemList .. sorry if my original question was confusing...

Comment: expected result 
ItemList - 43.00
ItemList - 42.00 etc